# How can I get Hex conversion working in sh

Tags: bash, sh, subshell

I want to make a script /bin/sh compatible. At some point I was using a print-out of a hex variable to its decimal value but it is throwing this error:

```
sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "16#c0"
```

That error is not present when the script is executed by /bin/bash. I boiled it down to the following problem:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $((16#c0))'     
sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "16#c0"

$ sh -c "echo $((16#c0))"    
192
```

Why is that and how can I get echo working in my script?

EDIT:
subshell is redirected to /bin/dash

```
$ readlink -f $(which sh)
/bin/dash
$ type sh
sh is /bin/sh
```

Comment: Surely you need `bash -c '...'` to have it executed by `bash`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I assume OP wants to do this in a POSIX compliant shell

Comment: exactly, I wanted to have it executed by sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sh` (often simlink to a POSIX shell like `dash`) doesn't support arithmetic evaluation in the form `[base#]n` like `bash` is supporting.

So you need to use the `0x` prefix with your hexadecimal number:

```
sh -c 'echo $((0xc0))'
```

or

```
sh -c 'printf "%d\n" 0xc0'
```

Note that you always need to use single quote to not let the current shell interpreting the content of the double quoted string.

So your attempt with

```
sh -c "echo $((16#c0))"
```

looks to be working only because the `$((16#c0))` is interpreted by `bash` and the actual command executed by `sh` is `echo 192`.

Comment: That was helpful. I never would have thought that the subshell could be something different than the "host" shell. Is there a way to to check this?

Comment: @user8162 Try `type sh` or `readlink -f $(which sh)` to see if this is a symbolic link to something else.

Comment: Technically, there's no subshell; you are running the program `sh` from a `bash` shell, not starting a new shell in the same process. The double-quoted argument is simply evaluated by `bash` before `sh` is ever executed; your second attempt is equivalent to `sh -c "echo 192"`.